# Flutter how to get subtext aligned under title in appbar?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following app bar in flutter and trying to align the subtext "Your desired business name" under the title enter. I have tried different methods but still can't get to align. It should have "enter" at the top and then the subtext aligned center

[image]

Here is my current code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(75.0), 
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('enter'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new Container(),
              new Center(
                  child: Text(
                'Your desired business name',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
            ],
          )),  
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The menu bar actions widgets get aligned on the right and as far as I know it is not possible to obtain your desidered layout.

Should you consider a column based widget with a title and subtitle:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Column(children: [
        Text(
          "Title",
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Text('subtitle'),
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped subtitle");
          },
        )
      ]),
      ...
```

In this example there is a `GestureDetector` for give interactivity to subtitle, since it seems it is what you are trying to do.

Comment: This worked the best but I removed that GestureDetector as I don't need that. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

To align Text under `AppBar` title you can use `bottom` property of AppBar which takes `PreferredSize` widget as a parameter which also helps you to adjust the height of AppBar according to your need.

Here's the code

```
AppBar(
    title: Text('Title 1'),
    centerTitle: true,
    bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: Text("Title 2"),
        preferredSize: Size.zero),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: It's too close to the bottom.

Comment: This solution is expired as `preferredSize` can't take `null` as a value in newer versions of dart. We have to explicitly specify a size now, like `Size.zero`.

Answer (score 17):

I am using this code for adding subtitle and show UserIcon

//`name,status and userPic are variable's`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              name,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            Text(
              status,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
            )
          ],
        ),

        leading: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(userPicUrl),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[new Icon(Icons.more_vert)],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**`Output`**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In these cases I prefer to use a ListTile:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar:
      AppBar(
        title:
          ListTile(
            title:
              Text("Enter", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
            subtitle:
              Text("Your desired business name", style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
          )
      ),
    );
}
```

If you need the Text widget centered just wrap it within a Center widget.

Answer (score 4):

You should add Column view.

```
title: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
             Text(
                  "Title",
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                 ),
             Text(
                 "Sub Title",
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
                 ),
            ]
           ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880971/9185192 works but with null safety landing in Dart it is not allowed to set `preferredSize` to `null`.

So the solution is to set `preferredSize` to zero or any other valid number.

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Title 1'),
    centerTitle: true,
    bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: Text("Title 2"),
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
   ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Wonder why no one mentioned `ListTile` as a possible solution. It provides both `title` and `subtitle` just as we need.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: ListTile(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Title',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Subtitle',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: Center(
        child: Text('Flutter Tutorial'),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.